# Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment

Tags: java, eclipse

While running a script, I am getting the following error message in the Eclipse console:

> Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.

---

- Java Version: 8
- IDE: [Eclipse v4.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Oxygen)
- Firefox version: 46

Comment: class file version 53 = Java 9. Your Java 8 JVM cannot execute Java 9 code.

Answer (score 622, accepted):

This is just a version mismatch. You have compiled your code using Java version 9 and your current JRE is version 8. Try upgrading your JRE to 9.

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
59 = Java 15
60 = Java 16
61 = Java 17
62 = Java 18
63 = Java 19
64 = Java 20
65 = Java 21
```

Comment: giving advice on the *logical* choice might not be a good solution at all... what if the project is run with jre-8 in the first place and someone accidentally compiled some module against 9?

Comment: I believe the upgrade still won't cause any troubles since there won't be any backward compatibility issues. And it was logical since i believe the compiler has got upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: you're thinking in terms of a small, sandbox project; for enterprise projects - this is never a easy shift. For example some bugs were fixed in 8 for generics that you were relying on side-effects of them in 7; or `HashMap` order has changed from 7 to 8... etc. I have faced this. *Simply* saying - move to 9 is a good option, but never a simple and fast one

Comment: if you're stating in terms of enterprise project levels, yes you are correct and I strongly agree with that point. Upgrading/downgrading is never a most viable option in such scenarios.

Comment: When I run java -version, I see JDK and JRE both as 1.8.0 .    Also in project -> properties-> Java compiler1.8 is there for compliance, Source compatibility, Generated .class files. Also, in Java build Path-> Libraries: JRE System Library [Java SE-1.8] is there. Still I get error: "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/nativex/NativeListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0" .    May I know, what is the issue here?

Comment: how?????????????

Comment: @AnishMittal your JDK is 1.8 but there are jars in your classpath that were compiled with a newer JDK and your 1.8 JDK can't use those Jars

Comment: and how to do it?

Answer (score 100):

You might see this error in IntelliJ as well and this comes up in Google.

I think it's a Gradle error more than an IDE error.

The fix (stolen from [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251407)) is configure Java 11 as a Gradle JVM in IntelliJ:

**File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle** and change Gradle JVM to 11

[image]

That screenshot stolen from the [Jetbrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251407) as well

Comment: is there a maven specific solution for this ?

Comment: This helped a great deal, I using Java 18 but the Gradle JVM was set to 17. thanks mate.

Answer (score 75):

### IDE: Eclipse Oxygen.3

To temporarily correct the problem do the following:

`Project menu` > `Properties` > `Java Compiler` > `Compiler compliance level` > `1.8`

A permanent fix likely involves installing JDK 9.

FYI 1.8 is what Java 8 is called.

### Side bar

I recently returned to Java after a foray into C# (a breath of fresh air) and installed Eclipse Oxygen onto a clean system that had never had Java installed on it before. This **default everything** with a brand new install of Eclipse Oxygen yet somehow or other Eclipse can't get its own parameters to match the jdk that's installed. This is the second project I created and the second time I ran into this headache. Time to go back to C#?

### Related Question

[has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876051/has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-runtime-class-file-versi/)

Answer (score 26):

You can try this way:

```
javac --release 8 yourClass.java
```

Comment: This is just a temporary solution. I honestly think this is could have been a comment not an answer

Comment: explanation, please

Comment: @johnk Basically, when compiling the code, he's compiling it for Java 8 not Java 9, meaning the code can execute on Java 8 JVM

Answer (score 16):

For Android Studio, menu *File* → *Project Structure* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Can you explain the screenshot?

Answer (score 10):

`53` stands for [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), so it means that whatever class you have has been compiled with [javac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac) 9 and you try to run it with JRE 8. Either recompile that class with `javac-8` or use the JRE 9.

Answer (score 9):

The solution for me was doing what Andrei Kuznetsov said on *[Failed to run Android project in the Idea 2020.3 EAP (OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0))](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251407/Failed-to-run-Android-project-in-the-Idea-20203-EAP-OutputBuildAction-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-Java)*, summarized in the following image:

[image]

> Root cause: IDEA sources are now compiled against Java 11. Known workaround is to configure Java 11 as a Gradle JVM. -- Andrei Kuznetsov

Answer (score 8):

For temporary solution just right click on **Project => Properties => Java compiler => over there please select compiler compliance level 1.8 => .class compatibility 1.8 => source compatibility 1.8**.

Then your code will start to execute on version **1.8**.

Answer (score 7):

I've reproduced the similar issue on Windows 10 in a format like:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class ...
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/.../ServiceApplication
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

After upgrading the project from Java 17 to Java 18.

I had project settings regarding to Java 18:

1. Command line:

   > ```
   > java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
   > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
   > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
   > ```

   [image]
2. *Project Structure* → *Project Settings* → *Project*:

   [image]
3. *Project Structure* → *Project Settings* → *Modules*:

   [image]
4. *Project Structure* → *Platform Settings* → *SDKs*:

   [image]

And the reason of this issue was:

I forgot to specify the correct version for *Run*/*Debug Configurations* -> *Build and run* to *Java 18* instead of *Java 17*:

[image]

As it was compiled with a [newer Java version](https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/), but running on the older one.

---

If it's a Maven-related issue, you can [modify POM](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) by specifying the `-source` and `-target` of the *Java Compiler*.

---

Additional helpful links:

1. [Setting the Java Version in Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version)
2. [Consuming JAR Artifact of a specific Java version](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-artifact-classifiers#3-consuming-jar-artifact-of-a-specific-java-version)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue from the console after building a JAR file in IntelliJ. Using the Java configuration to update to a newer version (menu *Windows* → *Configure Java* → *Update* → *Update Now*) didn't work and was stuck at version 1.8 (Java 8).

To switch to a more recent version locally, I had to install the Java 15 JDK from *https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html* and add that to my Java runtime environment settings.

[image: Java Runtime Environment Settings]

Answer (score 4):

Your JDK version: Java 8 
Your JRE version: Java 9

Here your JRE version is different than the JDK version that's the case. Here you can compile all the Java classes using JDK version 1.8. If you want to compile only one Java class, just change the `*.java` into `<yourclassname>.java`

```
javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8  *.java
```

Options:

`source`: The version that your source code requires to compile. 
`target`: The oldest JRE version you want to support.

Comment: Hi, this command is not working from any folder in the project. It says, "javac file not found: *.java"

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this because I found the other answers hard to understand.

Essentially your JRE is not updated and/or Eclipse is not configured to use the most recent JRE.

On Windows, go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Java -> update and proceed to update java

or if you don't have Java, go to Oracle's website and download the most recent JRE.

Once this is done, go into eclipse, and under the project view, right click on your project, select Java Build Path, double click on JRE System Library, then Select Workspace Default JRE 14.1.

If a recent version of Java doesn't show up here, it probably isn't installed. Check you JRE(NOT JDK) version and make sure it's recent. If it is, try restarting the computer then trying this again.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA and having this error, try this.

1. Command + , (Open Preferences)
2. Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
3. Gradle JVM > Change it to a proper version

Comment: "Change it to a proper version" has to be one of the most useful information on the internet

Answer (score 2):

IDE : **Eclipse 2021-09**

This is caused because you have compiled the code with java version 9 and have java8 installed. You don't have to update to solve this issue.

> Right click on project > properties > Java Compiler > *untick*-Enable
> project specific settings > configure workspace settings > *tick*-Use
> default compliance settings > Apply and Close.

---

Now your code should be executed properly.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In my case, I use the IntelliJ IDEA and set JDK11 as my SDK and JDK17 in the Gradle setting.

Just update my SDK as JDK17, it was solved.

Check the JDK in *Project Setting* (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>) → *SDK *

with

the Gradle JVM in *Preference* (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) → *Build Tools* → *Gradle JVM*

[image: Gradle JVM2]

Comment: On Mac, presumably?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project section, click on properties > then to Java compiler > check compiler compliance level is 1.8 , or there should be no yellow warning at bottom

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing Gradle dependencies works for me: Right click over the project → *Gradle* → *Refresh Gradle Project*.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your Project Facets.

*Project Properties* → *Project Facets*

Change the Java version to the same version you are using. That works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error in IntelliJ. Apparently, choosing Java 1.8 as the project SDK doesn't affect the [javac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac) compiler that's used to build the project.

To change that, go to *Settings* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Compiler* → *Java Compiler*, and change Project bytecode version to 8.

Comment: It should be change to 9

Answer (score 1):

> In build.gradle(app) update as below: (Worked for me)

```
 kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) / [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro), to see installed Java environments:

```
archlinux-java status
```

To use a different environment:

```
sudo archlinux-java set (an environment listed in a previous answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is getting as an example:

If your computer is running on an older version of Java and the [Neo4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) is compiled on the latest version, please try to install the same version or upper to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem with [SonarQube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube):

> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

SonarQube with AzureDevOps error output:

```
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.2.2472
INFO: **Java 1.8.0_231** Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2016 10.0 x86
INFO: User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\agent_a\_work\_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\5.4.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\agent_a\_work\189\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.4.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_AU", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.405s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/15M
##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

---

I had Java v11 installed on the SonarQube server, but the error is saying its the Build Agent that doesn't have Java v11.

I decided to add the Java v12 bin path to the Environment Variable Path for it to be detected.

Important: this needs to be done on the build agent

[image]

[For a Hosted Build Agent you can install JDK v11](https://www.codewrecks.com/post/azdo/pipeline/java-requirement-sonarcloud/) or use this PowerShell script step:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Download and Install Java v11'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
      $Command = "c:\jdk-11.0.15_windows-x64_bin.exe"
      $Parms = "/s"
      Write-Host [System.IO.File]::Exists($Command)
      if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($Command)) {
        Write-Host 'Downloading Java11.exe'
        Invoke-WebRequest https://yourOwnUrl.com/jdk-11.0.15_windows-x64_bin.exe -OutFile $Command
      }
      Write-Host [System.IO.File]::Exists($Command)
      & "$Command" $Prms
      [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15")
      [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ";$($env:JAVA_HOME)\bin")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm building with Visual Studio 2019 some C++ code that is using [ANTLR4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).
ANTLR4 is Java-based, and to use it I run Java commands as a custom build step.

Earlier that day I had updated my JRE (Java Runtime Environment) on my new laptop to 1.8.   Not thinking, since it's been a year since I ran ANTLR4 stuff... I need the full JDK to *compile* with java.  So I had a 1.8 *runtime*, but the Visual Studio 2019 build shell was finding the JDK 1.7 compiler.   Once I *installed* the 1.8 JDK, all was good.

So 80% of the time, JRE is fine for me... it's just when I need the full JDK, **doh** I need the full JDK.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was resolved by just installing an older version of [TestNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG). It looks like it compiles with my Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA and having this error, try this.

1. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (Open Preferences)
2. *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle*
3. *Gradle JVM* → Change it to a proper version

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Java configured in IDE by navigating to *Settings* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle*

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when initialisomg my project from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).
We need to match the version of **java.sourceCompatibility and jvmTarget** used for run and compile in the "build.gradle.kt" file.

Answer (score 0):

Last week, I updated my Mac's Android Studio from 2021.2.1 to 2021.3.1. Then our project was built failed for the similar reason:

> Cause: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been
> compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file
> version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
> file versions up to 53.0

I found several discussion on the Jetbrains YouTrack Forum: [Failed to run Android project in the Idea 2020.3 EAP (OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0))](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251407/Failed-to-run-Android-project-in-the-Idea-20203-EAP-OutputBuildAction-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-Java). The suggested workaround is to update the defined Gradle JDK version to JDK11, but many Android projects don't support Gradle JDK11, so does mine.

Another solution is to downgrade Android Studio from 2021.3.1 to 2021.2.1, and it worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everyone is using Windows for development, but if you use Linux, lower your Java version.

Maybe install JDK 8. The version table provided by @Nithin should give you an idea of which version you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring the version of the compiler to 1.8 (your required version), try the older version of Spring Boot. Currently, it is 3.0.0 by default, but you can try 2.7.6 instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My error was similar: " UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime"

Solution: I tried to update my JAVA version from 15 to 17 and it worked in my case rather than updating all JRE in the compiler or doing other things.

Simply download the updated version of JAVA and change the path in SYSTEM Variable to 17

Go back to the project and apply the below steps :

1. Select your project ---> click on properties (at last ) ----> Select JAVA Build PAth ---> change JRE from 15 to 17 ----> Apply ---> apply and close

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [TestNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG), by downgrading version to 6.14.3, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Spring Boot version to 2.5.2. It resolved the issue for me. Instead of trying to change your Java version, try changing your Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue, while I have defined the pathes to variables only for admin.
And have started the cmd as regular user.
My solutions were:
either start cmd as admin
or define the "Path", "ANDROID_HOME" and "JAVA_HOME" in the userVariablies field up ot the admin one in SystemVariables.

Answer (score -2):

For [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm) 2022.3, try:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
/opt/PhpStorm-223.7571.212/bin/phpstorm.sh
```