# Java version issue with maven-surefire-plugin while running mvn test in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, java-11

I tried building artifact in Jenkins with OpenJDK11. First I ran `mvn clean install -DskipTests` & build was successful.

But when I ran `mvn clean install`, I got following error for test classes.

```
<CLASS_NAME> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0


org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
<CLASS_NAME> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties> 
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            <compilerArguments>
                <indy/>
                <configScript>config.groovy</configScript>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5-01</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Please help me in fixing this issue in Jenkins

**Note**: I faced similar issue in my local also. I changed JAVA_HOME in **~/.mavenrc** file & the issue got resolved

Comment: May there are multiple java versions in jenkins server ? How does your jenkins project config ? Use jenkins pipeline?

Comment: I guess maven-compiler-plugin took Java version mentioned in pom.xml but not the maven-surefire-plugin.. Is there way to enforce java version in maven-surefire-plugin ?

Comment: Solution using ***toolchains.xml*** is what you might be looking for - https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/java9.html

Comment: After I changing JAVA_HOME in ~/.mavenrc file & the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a version mismatch. You have compiled your code in local using Java 8 and your Jenkins has JAVA 11. Upgrade your local code to Java 11 compatible.
This is the link for your perusal.

[Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your finding is correct.  After I changed JAVA_HOME in ~/.mavenrc file & the issue got resolved for me.