# run java class in cmd

Tags: java, cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L50Ml.png)

Here is my error I got.
I don't know what to do my jre is already on latest version so is my jdk.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment

Comment: type `java -version` to see what java version the runtime is. You might have multiple versions installed and the `java` command in cmd is using an old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change JDK to 1.8 I think. Its because you wrote this program in Java 13. Here is list :

```
45 = Java 1.1
46 = Java 1.2
47 = Java 1.3
48 = Java 1.4
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that.