# Docker run returns an exception: Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, java-8

I created a web application using Springboot and now I'm going to dockerize it and upload it into docker hub. So my `Dockerfile` is,

```
FROM openjdk:8

EXPOSE 8080

ADD target/spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

After creating `.jar` inside my target I'm building docker image using the following command,

```
docker build -t kubernatesimage
```

It builds the docker image successfully and when I run the `docker images` I can see the created image. But before uploading it into docker hub I need to run and check so I'm executing,

```
docker run -it  -p 4000:80 kubernatesimage
```

And this returns the following exception,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guru/springframework/SpringBootWebApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

According to @Nithin's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment) StackOverflow question, I found  this happens due to version missmatch and the java version codes,

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
```

But still, I have no idea what do I need to perform to solve the issue. I mentioned openjdk:8 in my `Dockerfile` and I run `java -version` to get the local JDK version and it returned

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
```

So do I need to change java version in my local machine or change my `Dockerfile`?

Comment: either you must recompile the code using the version your docker use, or you must update the java version of your runtime environment. Which, is your decision.

Comment: @Stultuske Hello ,How can I check the java version which my docker use are there any command ?

Comment: it's all in the error message:  this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Try same version in local and docker, hope it will be resolve

Comment: @Stultuske I see thanks for it, one more thing Please can I know what is the purpose of mentioning my openjdk version in my Dockerfile? If docker is using its own version(according to my case it's java 11) we do not need to mention openjdk version in myDockerfile right?

Comment: @HasanuzzamanRana So do I need to delete the current docker image and rebuild it

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake yes, try same version in local and docker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application shouldnt run either way because of  this  `docker run -it  -p 4000:80 kubernatesimage`  it should be  `docker run -it  -p 4000:8080 kubernatesimage`

Now concerning the issue : Your runtime version is 8 : because of your dockerfile is "FROM openjdk:8"  so your application will be running in java 8  environment =>version 52 ..
and you have compiled your application to jar file  "spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" by another version 55 which is java 11. So you have java version mismatch => The key is to make sure both the compile and runtime is using the same JDK.

One proposed fix is change your java version in pom.xml file

```xml
<project>
...
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

Another fix is to change the runtime version in dockerfile  to java 11 , there is  not possible to base your image on openjdk:11  however you can use this

```dockerfile
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

*note: you can still run a smaller compiled java version in bigger runtime env, i.e running a compiled 8 java version on java 11 runtime environment*

I hope I helped

Comment: Jar compiled with 1.8 can be launched with Java 11, so `using the same JDK` is not obligatory.

Comment: the other way is what happened. Thats why I recommended you using the same version