# Gradle sync failed: Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment accessible

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I try to build my gradle project and I get the following error:

`1:36 PM  Gradle sync failed: Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7d417077 (5 s 556 ms)`

[build.gradle](https://hastebin.com/iwovoroman.php) file

and no, I do not know gradle and no I am not planning on learning it, but I have no chioce. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17):

I've had a similar problem with an old BungeeCord plugin, which used Gradle 4.10. In my case - it seems like that old Gradle doesn't work properly with Java 16, so I've manually changed contents of `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to use Gradle 7.0.

**Old file:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-bin.zip
```

**New file:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
```

Now it works ok, no more Gradle errors.

Comment: After changing, I had to click "File -> Sync Project with Fradle files" to kick off the update.  Probably a restart would do the same.
Also, the version 7.0 was correct but is always changing, we had success picking the latest from the list at https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Answer (score 3):

I got this error in IntellJ when opening an Android project that someone sent me. It's a Gradle error and I'm not sure of the root cause. I *think* it's no Gradle JVM set in the .idea folder of whoever sent me the project.

My fix was explicitly set the Gradle JVM in IntelliJ in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle and set it to 11, or whatever. It's the same fix as another answer from me [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71580720/467509)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it can be cause by different things.

I solved it changing the JDK to the embedded android JDK and adding it to the path and `JAVA_HOME` environement variables.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error while using a download project. Here the problem is with the version compatibility of Java and Gradle. The project was using Gradle 4.10.1 and my Gradle JDK was 17 which caused the error, I just changed my Gradle JDK to version 11. This solved the error for me.

Solution:
Go to File -> Project Structure -> Project. and note your Gradle Version. [Gradle Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKczF.png)

Now go to this link: [Compatibility Matrix - Gradle User Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#:%7E:text=A%20Java%20version%20between%208,used%20for%20compile%20or%20test.) and look for a close enough Java version. [Compatibility Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ruQO.png)

Now go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle. Under Gradle JDK click Download JDK.[Gradle JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N99a7.png)

Select the version and Download then Apply. [Select Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSG0O.png)

Rebuild the Project now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by older gradle `distributionUrl`. To solve it, go to  `gradle-wrapper.properties` and replace the `distributionUrl`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```