# IntelliJ org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/WSDLToJava has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, java-8, java-11

I am getting the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TGN8.png)

For some reason IntelliJ compiles plugin JAR files with JDK 11 not 8.

I have the following configuration in Project Structure:
[IntelliJ Project Structure view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVPMb.png)

Gradle JVM:
[Gradle JVM view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlmIM.png)

Java Compiler:
[Java compiler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syl1C.png)

Also tried to change Boot runtime version, but in case I am using an old one IntelliJ won't open:
[Currently selected version of JBR version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCu1X.png)

JAVA_HOME is referencing to JDK 8:
[Windows JAVA_HOME variable value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPHfn.png)

Right now I don't have any ideas what to do. Any suggestions?

IntelliJ version: 2022.3.1

Gradle Wrapper version: 3.0

JDK version: 1.8

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: check this answer, because it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928824/gradle-with-wsdl2java-plugin/74961183#74961183

Comment: @kojot, thank you for your help. Indeed, by specifying cxf version, it can download jar files that support jdk 8.