# when i add jdk 1.8 in eclipse i this problems how to resolve this

Tags: java-8

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ashokit/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

how to solve this problmes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment)